# How can I force Firefox18 to prompt for filename if file already exists in download location?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am having trouble getting Firefox to prompt me for the filename when it saves a file.   I had this working but after a recent upgrade to version 18, it stopped working.

No matter what I try, Firefox prompts me for the CrystalReport.csv download but then it fails to notify me that the file already exists in the download location and therefore fails to prompt me for a new filename.   The result is that I get files in my default "Downloads" directory named :   'CrystalReport(1).csv', 'CrystalReport(2).csv', 'CrystalReport(3).csv', 'CrystalReport(4).csv', etc.

How can I force this or control it?

Here is how I initialize my profile.  Strangely, the prefs that I set below are not saved permanently to the prefs.js  file.  Aren't they supposed to? :

```
public static FirefoxProfile initializeFirefoxProfile() {
    FirefoxProfile profile = null;
    File profileDir = new File( profileFirefoxDir + System.getProperty("file.separator") + profileFirefoxName );
    if ( profileDir.exists() ) {
        logger.info("Loading Firefox profile from " + profileDir + " named \"" + profileFirefoxName + "\"" );
        profile = new FirefoxProfile( profileDir );
    } else {
        logger.info("Cannot find defined profile dir. Loading Firefox profile from system by name: \"" + profileFirefoxName + "\"" );
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
        profile = allProfiles.getProfile( profileFirefoxName );
    }
    profile.setPreference("app.update.auto", false);
    profile.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false);
    profile.setPreference("app.update.url", "");
    profile.setPreference("app.update.interval", 8640001);
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Windows\\Temp");
    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", true);
    return profile;
}
```

Comment: And if you downgrade to a previous version of Firefox it works OK?

Comment: No, it made no difference using Firefox 16.   I have decided to work around it by using Commons FileUtils to copy the file from "Download" into the location I am expecting it to be.  Still, it would be nice to know how to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest selecting the option "Always ask me where to save files" in the Downloads section on the General tab of Firefox Options dialog.

Going through about:config, I couldn't find an entry that corresponds to this, but you shouldn't need to add it to your profile manually if you use that option.

Otherwise, some add-ons provide the functionality to prompt you for a filename if the file already exists.

Comment: That isn't the option I need (as I said in my question).  I am using that setting and it does prompt me but the problem is that it saves automaticaly to the users "Downloads" directory and instead of detecting an already existing file and prompting for a new filename, it just auto saves a incremented filename.   It is as-if there is a certain behavior configured for Firefox that defaults to "Downloads" directory with default behaviors.  I need to override that, and if possible, without downgrading my firefox.

Comment: My apologies... Short of right-clicking and doing Save As... every time, or using an add-on, I'm not sure you can do it.

Comment: It is frustrating because it has been working for me up until recently.  Not sure what would cause this behavior change.

Comment: No solution was found, but I learned a lot more about how it works.  Thanks for trying to answer.